# How do I recover from a key constantly pressed overnight to login

Tags: keyboard, login, lightdm

Occasionally and accidentally a key on my keyboard is left pressed overnight. This means a character is constantly being entered into the login prompt.
When I return in the morning, I cannot do anything other than press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, login and enter `service lightdm restart`.

Is there any way to avoid this problem or recover from the situation without having to restart all of my windows etc?

Edit: I tried this again overnight and could reproduce it. Keys that do nothing are: the arrow keys, (<kbd>home</kbd>,<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd>,<kbd>del</kbd>), (<kbd>end</kbd>,<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd>,<kbd>del</kbd>), (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>del</kbd>), <kbd>del</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>return</kbd>.

However I did notice that caps lock worked. It shows the caps lock warning icon as normal. The mouse also did nothing, even when clicking the language icon or the power icon in the top right.

I am using ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried an overnight test but a short test proves this will work:

- Simultaneously press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to highlight and tap <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete.

It should save you 8 hours of holding down the <kbd>Back Space</kbd> key.

Comment: I did try pressing escape and return which did nothing. I will try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. As a short test leave your stapler on your keyboard over lunch :)

Comment: Good idea and shift home and then tapping backspace also works.

Comment: @ianorlin Thanks for the compliment. Actually anything you type replaces the highlighted text, so you could save a keystroke and just start typing your password.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Unfortunately, this did not work. See my comments above

Comment: @ashleysmithgpu sorry to hear your mouse and directional keys are non-functional. :(

Comment: Is ctrl+u ("clear from current to start of prompt") avaliable on lightdm login?